# Перевод Json в ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

Есть `ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>()`,

Я перевожу его в Json командой:  `new Gson().toJson(array)`

Как распарсить Json обратно в array?

Comment: `Gson.fromJSON(...)` по логике... Пробовали?

Comment: fromJSON почему то  парсит не как Integer, а как Double, и вылетает с ClassCastException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {}.getType();
List<Integer> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jArray != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
    listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
}
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037340/converting-jsonarray-to-arraylist)